# Lower bound degree of approximating polynomial

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, approximation-theory

I am reading about quantum query lower bounds (polynomial method). They state that any polynomial such that $p(0) \in [0,1/3]$ and $p(t) \in [2/3, 1]$ for each $t \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ has to have degree at least $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$. I fail to find an easy proof of this theorem.

Comment: Did your source have any indication whatsoever of what tools to use in the proof?

Comment: @Ian There are actually two sources cited, but I am not on university computer so I have troubles finding the full versions. Moreover there might be easier presentations of these results than those in original papers. H. Ehlich and K. Zeller. Schwankung von Polynomen zwischen Gitterpunkten. T. J. Rivlin and E. W. Cheney. A comparison of uniform approximations on an interval and a finite subset thereof.